# The set of critical value of polynomial functions

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f$ be polynomial function: $\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that the set of critical values of $f$ is finite.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.